# Can objects attached to requests in expressjs be tampered with?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express

In express.js we often attach objects to the req object in middleware, e.g. req.myObject. What prevents a user sending an http request that includes req.myObject already set to some value? For example, I could use req.myObject as part of authentication. Could a user set req.myObject = true when sending a request when it should really be false? Potentially an issue if req.myObject is set on some routes but not others but middleware that checks req.myObject is re-used across routes.

Comment: Not sure how would a user set anything on `req` using any http verb? The post params are in `req.body` and gets are in `req.query` and files are in `req.files`. Did i miss anything?

Comment: No - I thought the answer might be something like that, i.e. that expressjs doesn't permit the requestor to set anything on the request object other than a finite set of objects....but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`req` is an object created by Express when a request is received. It's not something passed directly from client to the server, in fact it isn't even available to client.

A client can only relay information to the server in some limited ways - GET query, POST form data, or route paths which are attached to the `req` object by Express as `req.query`, `req.body`, and `req.params` respectively.

Anything else attached to the `req` object is out of scope of the client, at least directly.

Related question: [Node.js request object documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251553/nodejs-request-object-documentation)